# CSS specify 2 fonts in the same line error

Tags: css

I specify 2 fonts to have different colors . One font is wrapped around an element called `<d>` and they are wrapped around an `<div>` class. The fonts are displyed together perfectly on firefox but in IE 9 or older , the browser displays them the same color , because the older version browser does not recongize the element called `<d>` and if I put it in an `<div>` . It would break an line.
How can I make the 2 fonts have different colors work on IE together

[image]

MY CSS

```
.b{float:left;background-color: #EEF2FB; 
   width: 230px;
  font-size: 20px; 
  font-family: CordiaUPC;
  color: #72757A;}

d{font-size: 20px; 
  font-family: CordiaUPC;
  color: #010203;
  margin-left: 5px;}
```

My HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="float.css">

  <div class="b"> Hello<d>Distance</d> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `<span>` tag to do this, it will keep things displaying in an *inline* manner. The reasoning for using a *span* is because, by default `<span>` is given a `display: inline` attribute while some other elements, like a `div` for example are given `display:block` as a default by the browser.

```
  <div class="b"> Hello<span>Distance</span></div>
```

**Updated Styles:**

```
.b{
  float:left;
  background-color: #EEF2FB; 
  width: 230px;
  font-size: 20px; 
  font-family: CordiaUPC;
  color: #72757A;
}

span{
  font-size: 20px; 
  font-family: CordiaUPC;
  color: #010203;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `<d>`, which doesn't even exist, use a `<span>`:

```
<div class="b"> Hello<span>Distance</span> </div>
```

Unlike `div`s, `span`s are set to `display: inline` by default. `div`s are `display: block`.

I do suggest you add an `id` to your `span` though, because you probably don't want **all** of your spans to act like this.

That would give you this HTML:

```
<div class="b"> Hello<span id="mySpan">Distance</span> </div>
```

And your CSS would then be:

```
.b{
  float:left;
  background-color: #EEF2FB; 
  width: 230px;
  font-size: 20px; 
  font-family: CordiaUPC;
  color: #72757A;
}

#mySpan{
  font-size: 20px; 
  font-family: CordiaUPC;
  color: #010203;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can use `<span>` in place of `<d>`, or you could  even use `<b>` if you like:

```
<div class="b"> Hello<b>Distance</b> </div>

b {
  font-size: 20px; 
  font-family: CordiaUPC;
  color: #010203;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: `<b>` is for bold, why would you change its default behavior?! this is definitely not a good idea...

Comment: Like `<span>`, `<b>` is a very handy inline hook for styling, as is `<i>`. They are used as styling hooks by some of the best minds in the business, so it's useful to know that they are available for this. They are just elements with no actual semantic value. They just have default browser displays that can be changed via CSS. To downvote the reply is an unfortunate mistake.

Comment: What is the advantage of using `<b>` over a `<span>`? This will just end up making your code very confusing because you will expect something to be bold, and then it won't be.

Comment: No especial advantage at all, except that it's shorter. Where it comes in handy is if you need several such hooks. It saves you from having to use various spans with classes, that's all. Because the original question had a `<d>` in there, I thought it would be fun to point out that it could simply be changed to `<b>`. There's no reason is should be considered confusing. Didn't mean to cause a war over it, though.

Comment: I would just hate for people to read this and think that it's wrong to use a `<b>` for this, because it isn't. It's just an option that's worth knowing about—and I can't see what's less readable about it. It would be nice to be able to share knowledge here without being blindly voted down.